# How to do a people detection and counting using JavaCV

Tags: detection, javacv

is there any classes in javacv to count the number of people or detect people in a certain location which we define on the video? Simply what i am doing is upload a video to the system and identify the people coming to the scene daily. This is not real time. I have recorded videos with me. How i am going to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a combination of a Face Detection/ Face Tracking System. This is not a simple problem. Have a look at the descriptions on this page: [Face Detection and Face Recognition with OpenCV](http://www.shervinemami.co.cc/faceRecognition.html). Converting this Code to JavaCV shouldnt be difficult, just browse to the JavaCV-Page and have a look at the examples provided.

Now you can grab the images from the video frame by frame, checking for faces on every image. If you found one, you start to track it, which means that you check for this face in a small area around this face. This is pretty much the problem: Consider another person entering the scene, approaching the first one, how do you differ them?

So in addition to Detection/Tracking you might need Recognition as well. The link above provides information about the well known Eigenfaces approach for Face Recognition.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. the thing is face are not clearly visible in these videos. these are cctv videos of streets. i am counting the number of pedestrians entering in to the scene. then?

Comment: Okay in this case you should dismiss a face detection approach. If the camera is static and not moving maybe you could try something with subtracting images. Just compare a static image/frame of the camera without any pedestrian with the other frames and track the changes. I would recommend you to read some papers to get a deeper insight about this topic.

Comment: the camera is static. subtracting images will give the motions of vehicles as well. so how am I extract only the pedestrians?